# Entity Framework Many to Many - Cannot get data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, many-to-many

I have introduced a many to many relationship between two of my existing tables. For this, I have added a third table, which contains only the Ids of the other two tables.

Since I am using EF, I have also added

`public virtual List<EntityOne> EntityOnes` in EntityTwo

and

`public virtual List<EntityTwo> EntityTwos` in EntityOne.

However, with this, when I get the EntityTwo object, it does not contain the associated EntityOne object. The list has a count of zero, even though the data is there in the tables.

Am I missing something here? Is there anything else, I need to do?

---

Not sure,if this is relevant, but I have also this in OnModelCreation

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<EntityOne>().
                HasMany(p => p.EntityTwos).
                WithMany(a => a.EntityOnes).
                Map(
                                m =>
                                {
                                    m.MapLeftKey("EntityTwoId");
                                    m.MapRightKey("EntityOneId");
                                    m.ToTable("EntityRelations");
                                });
            ////Make sure a context is not created by default.
        }
```

Comment: Do you have lazy loading enabled? If so, you will need to do a .Include("EntityName") in your query to include the associated table data. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Please show the code that you expected to fetch the related data. Without it, we can only guess what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class One
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    private ICollection<OneTwo> _oneTwos;
    public virtual ICollection<OneTwo> OneTwos
    {
        get { return _oneTwos ?? (_oneTwos = new List<OneTwo>()); }
        set { _oneTwos = value; }
    }
}

public partial class Two
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    private ICollection<OneTwo> _oneTwos;
    public virtual ICollection<OneTwo> OneTwos
    {
        get { return _oneTwos ?? (_oneTwos = new List<OneTwo>()); }
        set { _oneTwos = value; }
    }
}
```

Add navigation properties to the join class:

```
public partial class OneTwo
{
    public virtual int OneId { get; set; }
    public virtual int TwoId { get; set; }

    public virtual One One { get; set; }
    public virtual Two Two { get; set; }
}
```

Add composite key to the join class and configure relationships:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<OneTwo>() // composite primary key
                .HasKey(p => new { p.OneId, p.TwoId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<OneTwo>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.One)
                .WithMany(c => c.OneTwos)
                .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.OneId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<OneTwo>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.Two)
                .WithMany(c => c.OneTwos)
                .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.TwoId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    // TODO: handle orphans when last asociation is deleted
}
```

An alternative strategy is to configure EF relationships via EntityTypeConfiguration<>. The following many-to-many relationship implementation demonstrates that approach:

## City.cs

```
public partial class City
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    private ICollection<CountyCity> _countiesCities;
    public virtual ICollection<CountyCity> CountiesCities
    {
        get { return _countiesCities ?? (_countiesCities = new List<CountyCity>()); }
        set { _countiesCities = value; }
    }
}
```

## County.cs

```
public partial class County
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    private ICollection<CountyCity> _countiesCities;
    public virtual ICollection<CountyCity> CountiesCities
    {
        get { return _countiesCities ?? (_countiesCities = new List<CountyCity>()); }
        set { _countiesCities = value; }
    }
}
```

## CountyCity.cs

```
public partial class CountyCity
{
    public virtual int CountyId { get; set; }
    public virtual int CityId { get; set; }

    public virtual County County { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}
```

## CountyCityConfiguration.cs (EF 6 implementation)

```
public class CountyCityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CountyCity>
{
    public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<CountyCity> builder)
    {
        // Table and Schema Name declarations are optional
        //ToTable("CountyCity", "dbo");

        // composite primary key
        builder.HasKey(p => new { p.CountyId, p.CityId });

        builder.HasOne(pt => pt.County)
               .WithMany(p => p.CountiesCities)
               .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.CountyId)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasOne(pt => pt.City)
               .WithMany(t => t.CountiesCities)
               .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.CityId)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        // TODO: handle orphans when last association is deleted
    }
}
```

## Entity Framework 6 Implementations:

You may configure the composite key and relationships using EntityTypeConfiguration<> as the previous code demonstrates.

## Entity Framework Core Implementations:

EntityTypeConfiguration<> has not yet been migrated. However, it is on the roadmap for the next release.

In the meantime, you can employ the [temporary pattern suggested by the EF team](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2805#issue-99973931), or one of the patterns discussed this rather [lengthy StackOverflow post discussing entity configuration in Entity Framework 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957519/ef-7-mapping-entitytypeconfiguration/35373237#35373237).

I implemented the pattern posted by Cocowalla in the lengthy discussion prior to reading the EF Team post. The [source code for my workaround is available in this GitHub repository](https://github.com/RandyDaddis/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/tree/AspNetCoreMvcSampleCode.RefactoredGenericRepository).

## IEntityTypeConfiguration.cs

```
namespace Dna.NetCore.Core.DAL.EFCore.Configuration.Temporary.Cocowalla
{
    // attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957519/ef-7-mapping-entitytypeconfiguration/35373237#35373237
    public interface IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> where TEntityType : class
    {
        void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntityType> builder);
    }
}
```

Here is my implementation of that pattern:

```
namespace Dna.NetCore.Core.DAL.EFCore.Configuration.Common
{
    public class StateOrProvinceConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<StateOrProvince>
    {
        public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<StateOrProvince> builder)
        {
            // EF Core
            builder.HasOne(p => p.Country).WithMany(p => p.StateOrProvinces).HasForeignKey(s => s.CountryId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            builder.HasMany(d => d.Cities).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
            builder.HasMany(d => d.Counties).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
}
```