# Splitting DbContext according to

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, dbcontext

I would like to split into pieces my `DbContext` class so that each module has its own class which I believe makes working easier, more error throne and lowers code complexity.

I believe that I saw it somewhere in the past while googling however no luck of finding it.

My `DbContext` is in Infrastructure Layer, and My classes are in Domain Context. That is not problem. I would like to separate mappings and configurations into separate classes. My `DbContext` will remain same except it will be splitted.

I marked the code peaces I am willing to split into pieces below:

```
public class WestCoreDbContext : DbContext
{
    public WestCoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<WestCoreDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    #region WOULD LIKE TO SPLIT THIS PART
    public virtual DbSet<SoftwareTest> SoftwareTests { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SoftwareTestCase> SoftwareTestCases { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SoftwareTestCaseStep> SoftwareTestCaseSteps { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<SoftwareTestCaseStepResult> SoftwareTestCaseStepResults { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }
    #endregion

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        #region WOULD LIKE TO SPLIT THIS PART
        SoftwareTestMapping(modelBuilder);
        SoftwareTestCaseMapping(modelBuilder);
        SoftwareTestCaseMapping(modelBuilder);
        SoftwareTestCaseStepMapping(modelBuilder);
        SoftwareTestCaseStepResultsMapping(modelBuilder);
        PositionMapping(modelBuilder);

        RelationshipsMapping(modelBuilder);
        #endregion

        modelBuilder.MyOracleNamingConventions();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    #region WOULD LIKE TO SPLIT THIS PART

    private void SoftwareTestMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTest>();
    }

    private void SoftwareTestCaseMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTestCase>();
    }

    private void SoftwareTestCaseStepMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTestCaseStep>();
    }

    private void PositionMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Position>();
    }

    private void SoftwareTestCaseStepResultsMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTestCaseStepResult>();
    }

    private void RelationshipsMapping(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTest>().HasMany(x => x.SoftwareTestCases).WithOne(op => op.SoftwareTest).IsRequired().HasForeignKey(@"StId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTestCase>().HasOne(x => x.SoftwareTest).WithMany(op => op.SoftwareTestCases).IsRequired().HasForeignKey(@"StId");

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTestCase>().HasMany(x => x.SoftwareTestCaseSteps).WithOne(op => op.SoftwareTestCase).IsRequired().HasForeignKey("StcId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTestCaseStep>().HasOne(x => x.SoftwareTestCase).WithMany(op => op.SoftwareTestCaseSteps).IsRequired().HasForeignKey("StcId");

        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTestCaseStep>().HasMany(x => x.SoftwareTestCaseStepResults).WithOne(op => op.SoftwareTestCaseStep).IsRequired().HasForeignKey("StcsId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTestCaseStepResult>().HasOne(x => x.SoftwareTestCaseStep).WithMany(op => op.SoftwareTestCaseStepResults).IsRequired().HasForeignKey("StcsId");
    }
    #endregion

    public bool HasChanges()
    {
        return ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
    }

    ...
}
}
```

I dont know exact way of splitting DbContext. 
I need a way for doing this. can you provide me solution?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I am not sure about how to split DBContext into smaller pieces. I want to have 1 DbContext but with smaller pieces. Its seperation of concerns issue for me.

Comment: Have you even tried to do it? Just copy this class, give it a new name and remove the bits you don't need.

Comment: it seems you try to do this within one class, which does work, but it will need refactoring. The easy way to do it would be to have several DbContext classes, as you cannot make properties unavailable within a class. An interface could be a solution, if you do have a minimal working requirement. Note however that code complexity will hardly be affected by this approach, and saving in model building can only be done with several classes (if you do not want to refactor your BL to not use the DbSet properties)

Comment: Note that `context.Set<T>()` will always provide access to all mapped entities in the context. This may be one of the rare case where an extra abstraction layer of Unit of Work/Generic Repository is justified. Also note that the compiled model belonging to one context class will only be built once per application life span. You can't compile a model per instance (well, it's possible but not recommended). So if that's what you mean by "splitting" be aware that you need different context *classes* for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You first have o be clear what you mean with split the `DbContext`. You say that it is a separation of concerns issue, so you should first decide which concerns you want to separate. The `DbContext` handles the concern of mapping the database table to an object model and so it makes sense that it does everything related to that. The other end of separation of concerns is to not split a concern into pieces since that too increases program complexity.

A good separation of concerns is to keep the `DbContext` together and let it do the basic work of mapping the DB to your object model. Additional tasks, like specialized queries to the DB would be encapsualted in repositories that would use the `DbContext`, which also allows you to abstract your business layer from the actual entity framework implementation.

On top of that there are still some ways you can "split" your `DbContext` into pieces:

**Make the `DbContext` a partial class**

You can make `WestCoreDbContext` a [partial class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) and split its contents over multiple code files. You should be clear though that the compiled output will be exactly the same, so you don't really improve separation of concerns in an OOP sense. You can also argue if splitting a single class to multiple code files without a good reason (like the class being partially auto-generated) will actually increase or decrease manageablity of your code. This is a decision you have to make for yourself.

**Use entity type configuration classes**

You can configure your entity classes with the fluent API using classes derived from [`EntityTypeConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117.aspx) (or implementing the [`IEntityTypeConfiguration` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ientitytypeconfiguration-1?view=efcore-2.0) in .net Core 2.0), which let you to configure your entity classes outside the `DbContext`. This can actually help manageability when you have a larger amount of entity classes, where the `OnModelCreating` method would become very long.

In your case this would look like this in .net Core 2.0 (I have simplified your example):

```
public class WestCoreDbContext : DbContext
{
    public WestCoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<WestCoreDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<SoftwareTestCase> SoftwareTestCases { get; set; }
    //Define further DbSets

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new SoftwareTestCaseConfiguration());
        //Apply further configurations

        modelBuilder.MyOracleNamingConventions();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public bool HasChanges()
    {
        return ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified || e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
    }
}

//This configuration class is separated from the WestCoreDbContext and can go into a separate code file
internal class SoftwareTestCaseConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<SoftwareTestCase>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SoftwareTestCase> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTestCase>().HasOne(x => x.SoftwareTest).WithMany(op => op.SoftwareTestCases).IsRequired().HasForeignKey(@"StId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareTestCase>().HasMany(x => x.SoftwareTestCaseSteps).WithOne(op => op.SoftwareTestCase).IsRequired().HasForeignKey("StcId");
    }
}
```

If you are not on .net Core 2.0, check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957519/ef-core-mapping-entitytypeconfiguration) to achieve the same result.

Comment: Does .Net Core still allow something like `modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(SoftwareTestCaseConfiguration).Assembly);` to collect all configurations of a class library project?

Comment: @grek40: Check out [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder?view=efcore-2.0). There is nothing like that on `ModelBuilder` or its extension methods.

Comment: "entity type configuration classes" is exactly what I am looking for. thank you very much for your time.  I am considering to put dbSets into partial classes  <code>public virtual DbSet<SoftwareTestCase> SoftwareTestCases { get; set; }</code>

Comment: `modelBuilder` as parameter name is kind of missleading since it's an entity configuration.   In the interface, the parameter is only called `builder`. Inside the configure method, just configure like `builder.ToTable('bla');` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EF Core power tool and that will handle automatically. [image]