# EF Core Fluent Api chaining configuration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

How can I chain this in EF Core Fluent API, instead of repeating line by line for each property of table:

```
        builder.Entity<FoodWeight>().HasIndex(x => x.NutrientDatabankNumber);
        builder.Entity<FoodWeight>().Property(x => x.NutrientDatabankNumber).HasColumnName("NDB_No");
        builder.Entity<FoodWeight>().Property(x => x.SequenceNumber).HasColumnName("Seq");
        builder.Entity<FoodWeight>().Property(x => x.Amount).HasColumnName("Amount");
        builder.Entity<FoodWeight>().Property(x => x.Description).HasColumnName("Msre_Desc");
        builder.Entity<FoodWeight>().Property(x => x.GramWeight).HasColumnName("Gm_Wgt");
        builder.Entity<FoodWeight>().Property(x => x.GramWeight).HasColumnName("Gm_Wgt");
        builder.Entity<FoodWeight>().Property(x => x.NumberOfDataPoints).HasColumnName("Num_Data_Pts");
        builder.Entity<FoodWeight>().Property(x => x.StandardDeviation).HasColumnName("Std_Dev");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always add an extension method to `EntityTypeBuilder`, but this doesn't reduce the verbosity greatly:

```cs
modelBuilder
    .Entity<FoodWeight>()
    .Configure(
        entity => entity.HasIndex(x => x.NutrientDatabankNumber),
        entity => entity.Property(x => x.NutrientDatabankNumber).HasColumnName("NDB_No"),
        entity => entity.Property(x => x.SequenceNumber).HasColumnName("Seq")
    );
```

And the extension method:

```cs
public static class EntityTypeBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void Configure<T>(this EntityTypeBuilder<T> modelBuilder, params Action<EntityTypeBuilder<T>>[] builders) where T : class
    {
        builders
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(builder => builder(modelBuilder));
    }
}
```

Comment: A far better approach is to use `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` classes to configure your mappings. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957519/ef-core-mapping-entitytypeconfiguration