# How to mimic Entity Framework type-based configuration

Tags: c#, .net-core

I do not know the term to set a proper question title but I have some classes

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Prop1;
    public string Prop2;
    public string Prop3;
}

class MyClassOther
{
    public string PropOther1;
    public string PropOther2;
    public string PropOther3;
}
```

I would like to make a Configuration class that can map a property to an excel file for example

```
Configuration<MyClass>
```

where I can do

```
configuration.Property(p => p.Prop1).HasCell("A1")
```

[Like Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957519/ef-core-mapping-entitytypeconfiguration)

And later from that configuration, I can get the property value from expression `(p => p.Prop1)` to map to cell `"A1"`

Without that kind of configuration I can just store the property and the cell in any text form `{"Prop1","A1"}` and do something like this

```
Cell["A1"] = myClassInstance.GetType().GetProperty("Prop1").GetValue(myClassInstance, null);
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616638/access-the-value-of-a-member-expression? What exactly is the question you have? Or what is the problem you have? Please show your attempts and the errors/problems you have with them.

Comment: MemberExpression seems like what I am looking for. Never aware of that before. I will take a look at the documentation. Thanks @Progman

Comment: Updated to better reflect what I did and wanted to avoid @Progman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to achieve this won't be hard, but you will have to write everything from scratch as I don't believe there is anything like that already implemented.

To start, please rewrite your classes so that they are using properties:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now start creating your configuration class (take it more like a direction, there will be a lot of code in the end):

```
// Config class
// In real life, you don't want to use static class and method, instead, use injection
 public static class Configuration<TEntity>
 {
     public static PropertyConfigurationBuilder<TEntity, TProperty> Property<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
     {
         return new PropertyConfigurationBuilder<TEntity, TProperty>(propertyExpression);
     }
 }
```

And finally a builder class for syntax chaining:

```
public class PropertyConfigurationBuilder<TEntity, TProperty> 
{
    private Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> _propertyExpression;

    public PropertyConfigurationBuilder(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
    {
        _propertyExpression = propertyExpression;
    }

    public void HasCell(string cell)
    {
        // Do actuall logic with the Excel sheet here
        // To do this, you actually need to access it, so you probably need to inject reference to the actuall sheet
        // You also probably don't want to return 'void' but some other builder so you chain your syntax same way Entity Framework does it
    }

}
```

With these simple code snippets, you should be able to use the syntax you want:

```
public class Usage
{
    public void Map()
    {
        Configuration<MyClass>.Property(e => e.Prop1).HasCell("A2");
    }
}
```

This should be a good starting point for you. I would like to help you further but I am not sure what parts of the implementation you find challenging and there is quite a lot of code and topics to cover.

Feel free to ask further!