# Create a foreign key on a table in entity framework core that references the identity user table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys, asp.net-identity

I am trying to create relationships from the AspNetUsers table autogenerated by AspNet Identity to tables created by myself. Ex. Table A has a UserId column set to nvarchar(128) and I want it to relate to the UserId column the AspNet Users table. This is an Asp.Net MVC web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first I have some considerations you should not use nvarchar as FK much less as UserId because it is much more performant for a structural database like SQL to index but if you are using non-structural ignore this ...

good now for your solution see relationships between tables must be done through a ConfigMap where the entityFramework understands the relationships between objects and map them to the database I will give you an example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure StudentId as FK for StudentAddress
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasRequired(s => s.Address) 
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(ad => ad.Student); 

}
```

consider these classes as relation objects

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentAddress Address { get; set; }
}
     
public class StudentAddress 
{
    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentAddressId { get; set; }
        
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

see that the mapping on how the relationship should occur was done here OnModelCreating

there is another way to do it by making a configuration class for each object/table in the database that way it would be more organized

```
class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
  {
     builder.HasKey(c => c.AlternateKey);
     builder.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(200);
   }
}
```

example:
[EF Core Mapping EntityTypeConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957519/ef-core-mapping-entitytypeconfiguration)

I can also put the entityFramework documentation as a good guide for its development
1:1
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

1:N
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

N:N
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

I really hope I helped with your question.

another point did not comment but you should study about migrations and use them in your project to version your changes in the database

[https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-migration.aspx#:~:text=Migration%20is%20a%20way%20to,on%20the%20EF%20Core%20model](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-migration.aspx#:%7E:text=Migration%20is%20a%20way%20to,on%20the%20EF%20Core%20model).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps quite a bit. However to answer your concerns, the reason I'm using varchar for the PK on the table is because the user table created by ASP.NET Core Identity has a varchar PK that is actually a GUID. I'm beginning to think that there may not be a way for me to do what I want to do.